# Why would anyone do Catch (Exception e) { throw e; }?

Tags: c#, error-handling, try-catch

Why would anyone do this? I do not understand. Can I delete this try-catch block without affecting the code?

```
try
{
    Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> svnLog = GetSVNRevisionsLog(lastRevision, currentRevision, svnUrl);

    svnInfo = PopulateOutput(svnLog, svnUrl.ToString());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you want to log or something and re-throw, but yes in this case it's safe to delete

Comment: It's actually better to delete it because as it's written now re-throwing the e exception object is stomping out your stack-trace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why would anyone do this?

You shouldn't do this.  The closest you should come would be if you wanted to add some logging, in which case you should write:

```
try
{
  /// Do something
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   LogException(e); // Do some logging
   throw; // Don't use throw e
}
```

The `throw` statement, when used alone, preserves the exception call stack information.

That being said, if you don't have other logic (such as logging), there is absolutely no reason to catch the exception.  Exceptions should only be caught if you need to either log/process them, or if you can reasonably handle the error and recover properly.

Comment: I like this answer in that you say Exceptions shouldn't be caught but prevented by additional logic.

Answer (score 2):

Might be case where **developer doesn't want to expose actual call stack to the user** because `throw e` **resets the stack trace** (so your errors would appear to originate from method where try block is applied)

However, **simply throw preserve stack trace**. So, this doesn't make any sense unless you have other code above throw:

```
try
{
    Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> svnLog =
          GetSVNRevisionsLog(lastRevision, currentRevision, svnUrl);

    svnInfo = PopulateOutput(svnLog, svnUrl.ToString());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That try/catch block make no sense. You only have to catch exceptions if you plan to do something with it but in that case nothing is done (just throwing the exception doesn't count as doing something as this is done anyway). You can safely remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should remove the try catch. You should catch the specific type of exception, also, if you try-catch, then throw, the call stack information of the original exception is lost, and the call stack information is very important for the debugging.

So, in general, don't try catch every thing.